# Json parsing using http post method not working

Tags: iphone, json

i have to parse a json using http post method but i am always getting the response that the method not been implemented.But it works for post method.this is my code

```
NSString *password = txtPassword.text;
NSArray *objects = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"sintu",@"sintugeorge",@"auth.gettoken", nil];
NSArray *keys = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"username",@"password",@"method",  nil];
NSDictionary *theRequestDictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:objects forKeys:keys];
NSString *theBodyString = [theRequestDictionary JSONRepresentation];
NSData *theBodyData =  [theBodyString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [theBodyData length]];

NSURL *theURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://192.168.1.11/elggapi/services/api/rest/json"];
NSMutableURLRequest *theRequest = [[[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init] autorelease];
[theRequest setURL:theURL];
[theRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[theRequest setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[theRequest setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[theRequest setHTTPBody:theBodyData];

NSLog(@"%@", theBodyString);
NSURLResponse *theResponse = NULL;
NSError *theError = NULL;
NSData *theResponseData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:theRequest returningResponse:&theResponse error:&theError];
NSString *theResponseString = [[[NSString alloc] initWithData:theResponseData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] autorelease];
// NSLog(theResponseString);
NSDictionary *theResponseDictionary =(NSDictionary*)[theResponseString JSONValue] ;

NSLog(@"%@", theResponseDictionary);
```

Comment: can you please re-format your code... in the question body

Answer (score 1):

I am using [ASIHTTP](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/) to get data from APIs. So this is what i am doing for get data if it is in POST method

```
ASIFormDataRequest *request = [[ASIFormDataRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://mobile.sample.com/IPhone/SingleAPI/Preview"]];
[request setDelegate:self];
[request setRequestMethod:@"POST"];
[request setPostValue:messagetele forKey:@"message"];

[request setPostValue:D_Name forKey:@"deliveryName"];
[request setPostValue:D_Address forKey:@"deliveryAddress"];
[request setPostValue:D_City forKey:@"deliveryCity"];
[request setPostValue:D_ZipCode forKey:@"deliveryZipCode"];
[request setPostValue:D_State forKey:@"deliveryState"];
[request setPostValue:D_Country forKey:@"deliveryCountry"];

[request setPostValue:S_Name forKey:@"senderFromName"];
[request setPostValue:S_City forKey:@"senderYourCity"];
[request setPostValue:S_Email forKey:@"senderYourEmail"];
[request setPostValue:S_Country forKey:@"senderYourCountry"];

[request startAsynchronous];
```

an this is what i am doing for get data if it is in GET method

```
NSString *url = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.sample.com/IPhoneAPI/Search?uuid=%@&appkey=%@&page=%d&type=%@&criteria=%@&country=%@",uuid,@"TNaNpiJwd6wjDM5fGKYZyPDyMU93", [Globals sharedGlobals].pageNumber,@"suburb",[[Globals sharedGlobals].searchText objectForKey:@"text"],countryName];

ASIFormDataRequest *request = [[ASIFormDataRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];

[request setTimeOutSeconds:30];

[request setRequestMethod:@"GET"];

[request setDelegate:self];

[request startAsynchronous];
```

Both of these are calling net Asynchronously.

After receving data in JSON fromat .. i am calling this method

```
- (void)requestFinished:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request
{   
    NSString *responseString = [request responseString];

    SBJSON *parser = [[SBJSON alloc]init];
    NSDictionary *data = (NSDictionary*) [parser objectWithString:responseString error:nil];

    tempOffers = [[data objectForKey:@"offers"]retain];
```

I am collecting that JSON response and put that in to array or dictionary and using it.

This is my way of calling APIs and getting data. Hope this will help you. Thanks :)